# JSON data into Numbers

Tags: applescript, numbers

I'm new to applescript, and found this language very hard to use. I try to write applescript that will fetch the token prices and symbols, and put them into Numbers. To do that we have to call the API 2 times. First one to get all the ids of tokens, and the second to use those ids as a comma separated list parameter.

First request:

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list
```

Second request:

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=[ids-from-previous-one]&vs_currencies=usd
```

I get some inspiration from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8126136 but it relates to scrapping webpage rather than parsing JSON. I also found some parsing examples but still very confused, and couldn't manage to parse the document. I have JSON helper installed.

What I have so far is:

```
set mySheetName to "Prices2"
set myTableName to "Coin Prices"
set tgtCell to "A2"  

tell application "JSON Helper"
    set json to fetch JSON from "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list"
    return json
end tell

<some magic here>
```

I have no idea what to do next.

Does anyone knows how to tackle that?

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to do this in **AppleScript**, with or without **JSON Helper**, nonetheless, due to the number of records retrieved (8888) and the time it takes to iterate over them compared to a *shell script* solution, **AppleScript** is not the best way to retrieve and parse the *data*.

As a test I did use **AppleScript** to create a **CSV** *file* from the retrieved *data* and it took 19+ minutes compared to 5 seconds using a *shell script* to do the same thing.

That said, I'm posting the *example* **shell script** *code* I used to retrieve the *data* and create a **CSV** *file* using the *third-party utility*: [**jq**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cd /private/tmp || exit
curl 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list' -o coins.json
printf '%s\n' "ID,SYMBOL,NAME" > coins.csv
jq -r '.[] | [.id, .symbol, .name] | @csv' coins.json >> coins.csv
open -a "Numbers" coins.csv
```

- <sup>The *example* **shell script** *code* is just that, an example. It can be written to accommodate *command line arguments*, such as the **URL** and *filenames*, etc.</sup>

**Notes:**

The order in `[.id, .symbol, .name]` was used just because that's the way it is in the raw *data* at the website and also how it's retrieved using `curl`, while **JSON Helper** changed the order to `id, name, symbol`.  You can change the order in the `printf` *statement* and the `jq` *query* as you'd like.

If you don't have or use **Homebrew**, you do not need it in order the get `jq` as a precompiled binary is available. It's not packaged and once downloaded as e.g. `jq-osx-amd64`, I did the following in **Terminal**:

```
cd Downloads
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine jq-osx-amd64
mv jq-osx-amd64 jq
chmod +x jq
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo mv -nv jq /usr/local/bin/
```

To use the *example* **shell script** *code*, in **Terminal**, run the following *compound command*:

```
f="fetchcoins"; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod +x "$f"
```

In the opened **fetchcoins** *document*, copy an paste the *example* **shell script** *code* into it and then save and close it.

Back in **Terminal**:

```
sudo mv -nv fetchcoins /usr/local/bin/
```

**That's it, you're all set to use it in **Terminal**:**

```
fetchcoins
```

---

<sub>About using **AppleScript**, whether one parses the *data* to a **CSV** *file* or writes the *code* to populate the *cells* in a **Numbers** *spreadsheet* as the *data* is iterated over, because of the extreme time differential I'm not going to provide the *example* **AppleScript** *code* I used unless requested. Although to be blunt, please don't ask and use `jq` as it is the proper tool to use in this use case.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, looks awesome. I think the ultimate workflow will be to run that script once a day, and have another script that will run 2-3x per day to fetch current prices. Than there will be applescript run on demand, that will get result json and put the data into the proper table in Numbers, as I have spreadsheet dedicated for that.
What I mostly struggle with is a semantic how to use JSON helper to process data, especially when especially when there are many levels in data file.

Comment: @Navidot, **JSON Helper** is only good for one thing in this use case and that is to convert **JSON** to an **AppleScript** _record/list_, then independently of **JSON Helper**, is to then iterate the **AppleScript** _record/list_ that was converted from **JSON**. This involves an **AppleScript** [`repeat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-127362) _statement_, e.g. `repeat with thisItem in thisList` or `repeat with i from 1 to count thisList`

Comment: @Navidot, A good **AppleScript** tutorial on **Numbers** can be found at: [**Numbers & AppleScript**](https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/index.html)

Comment: I don't think it's right to answer "how to do this with Python" with "here's Java, don't ask for Python again". If it really is that slow then OP will see it and decide by itself to use something else. You don't know in which context OP is in and why they decided to use AppleScript, and other people could come here from the web wishing to find AppleScript code (me!) and get frustrated. You might also have gotten something wrong that made it slow and someone else could fix it. I think it's fine suggesting something else would be better suited but this doesn't answer the question on AppleScript.

Answer (score -1):

I hope it guides you

```
set mySheetName to "Prices2"
set myTableName to "Coin Prices"
set tgtCell to "A2"
set id to "bitcoin"
set BASE_URL to "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list"
set coinUrl to BASE_URL & "?" & "id=" & id

tell application "JSON Helper"
    set json to fetch JSON from 
    return json
end tell

set symbol to symbol of response

tell application "Numbers"
    tell table myTableName of sheet mySheetName of document 1
        set the value of cell tgtCell to symbol
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does and how it can be used to solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: This sample code to fetch from https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list and set a cell in the Numbers. It query by ID (in this sample 'bitcoin') and set the cell by symbol in the response.

Comment: Please *edit* your answer with details.